# Fibonnaci Search arrays algorithmsss

Tags: data-structures

the keys 34, 12, and 45 using the Fibonacci search algorithm. Showing the complete algorithm

```
  Elements:  12  26  34  40  43  45  65  68  74  78  89  98  120  125
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to answer that im very confused